# Red Hat Registration(rhn_register)

Tags: redhat, rhel, rhel6, rhel5

I tried **rhn_register** command to register for Red Hat(**RHEL5**).

Later I got the screen saying...

[image]

But after few minutes I got the screen saying can't connect the Red hat.

[image]

When I checked the **/var/log/up2date** file , below is the tail output

*[root@mdw ~]# tail -f /var/log/up2date
[Mon Oct 24 23:54:36 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #1*

*[Mon Oct 24 23:56:01 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #2*

*[Mon Oct 24 23:57:26 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #3*

*[Mon Oct 24 23:58:51 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #4*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:00:16 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #5*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:25:25 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #1*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:26:50 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #2*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:28:15 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #3*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:29:40 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #4*

*[Tue Oct 25 00:31:05 2016] rhn_register A socket error occurred: (-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'), attempt #5*

By looking at the **/var/log/up2date** file, it seems some problem with name resolution (not sure). Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ruled out network issues on your side? Can you resolve/ping any other hosts?

Comment: @omajid Yes, I am able to ping to other hosts. I have resolved the issue. Thanks